# Control characters handling in XML

Tags: sql, xml

I am following XML based transport of data using FOR XML AUTO. When a column containing control character was encountered and a XML transform as below was attempted, it resulted in an exception:

```
DECLARE @TrialData NVARCHAR(200) = ''; --Not empty string..contains a control character '<-' 

DECLARE @TrialDataInHex VARBINARY(100)
SET @TrialDataInHex = CONVERT(VARBINARY(100),@TrialData)
SELECT @TrialDataInHex; -- returns 0x1B00 looks like this '<-'
```

Now, when I try to insert the same into XML variable like below

```
DECLARE @a_XML XML;
SET @a_XML = @TrialData;
```

This resulted in

> XML parsing: line 0, character 0, unrecognized input signature

Can Anyone suggest how control characters are usually handled when XML FROM SQL data medium is used?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap that value in an XML element:

```
XMLELEMENT("TrialData" , @TrialData)
```

generates

```
<TrialData>←</TrialData>
```

Comment: This does not work on t-sql. Can you suggest a t-sql equivalent. The one which works on MS SQL Server. I tried FOR XML AUTO PATH / ELEMENTS but none of them are letting me store this control character into a XML variable.

Comment: `SET @a_XML = '<TrialData>' +  @TrialData + '</TrialData>'`

Comment: Gives you the error : "XML parsing: line 1, character 12, illegal xml character". Your answer does not work with Control characters.

Comment: Another avenue of research: `sql:variable("@TrialData ")`